# dynamic_cast with dynamically loaded class causes undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference, dynamic-cast, dlopen

I have a C++ class whose definition is going to be loaded at run-time through `dlopen`. I can't get it to link though. I get errors saying there is an "undefined reference to typeinfo".

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
class Interface { ... };
class Impl : public Interface { ... };

Interface *Create() { ... }

// Load shared object around here

Impl *impl = dynamic_cast<Impl*>(Create()); // Undefined reference to typeinfo
```

I tried adding `-rdynamic` to my linker command, but this didn't seem to change anything. Is there something I can do about this?

Since I saw many questions about the same error message caused by undefined virtual functions, I should mention that I'm sure this is *not* my problem.

Also I should add that I'm sure this is related to dynamic_cast, because if I replace the dynamic_cast with a normal `(Impl*)` cast the code links correctly.

Comment: Please show your `dlopen` and `dlsym` code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: How is that relevant? This happens at link time.

Comment: @Elektito Link time for a .so is when you call `dlopen`.  If you're getting errors when you're invoking `ld` (through `g++`), then we'll need to know what options you've used there and to compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Errors are indeed happening when ld (through g++) is called. Options passed to g++ are `-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-Bdynamic` along with a few -l options for libraries. I created a minimal test case which I'm compiling/linking with a simple `g++ foo.cc` and it still causes the same error.